# Calling secured web service

Tags: wsdl, cxf

I am having difficulty making connection to secured webservice.  My service provider gave me a WSDL URL (which uses SSL Connection) and a PFX file.  The service provider told us that WSDL can only be accessed by users belonging to our network.

So far I have tried:

(i) Exported key from given pfx file to separate keystore

(ii) Exported certificate to (a) java 's default truststore (b) seaparate store

I have set system properties:

```
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/Test/keystore.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "test123");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

I am using latest versions of CXF & Java.  I got several exceptions which I could resolve by Googling the issues, but I am finally struck with "could not send message exception".  How can I deal with this exception?

Comment: Share the complete stacktrace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273476/client-for-secured-proxy-service/16273681?noredirect=1#comment23399509_16273681